# Why active nav pills content not showing properly

Tags: css, bootstrap-5, nav, nav-pills

I am trying to use Boostrap 5 nav pills, but the content of the nav pills are not showing properly.I am using 3 nav pills, after 3rd pill, content of 3rd pill shows up in first pill and the first pill content not showing, 2nd and 3rd pill content are working.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="active nav-link " data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>




<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
    <h3>HOME</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane "><br>
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane "><br>
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I got output as :

[image: Output]

My expected output as;[image: expected]

How to make these nav pills work properly?

Comment: your code snippet works as expected. You can omit the second script. Are you migrating from bootsrap 4 to 5?

Comment: Check the hrefs on your nav and make sure you're not linking them differently in whatever template you're working with or using the same IDs multiple times.

Comment: @ AStombaugh. Thankyou for figuring out, I have used same id

Answer (score 0):

The markup you provided works as expected. You should check that bootstrap script is loading correctly.
See the code below.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="active nav-link " data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
  </li>

</ul>




<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
    <h3>HOME</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane "><br>
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane "><br>
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still having issue, not working

Comment: How are you loading bootstrap?

Comment: I have template files also loading. I am integrating to my template

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine.